# Matroska audio reports wrong bitrate when adding a cover

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, matroska

I'm trying to make an audio-only Matroska file, but keep having an issue in regard to the reported bitrate of the archive.

To demonstrate it, I'm first making a simple .mka without any attachments using the following ffmpeg command:

> ffmpeg -i original.opus -acodec copy output.mka

When I check the resulting file with MediaInfo and foobar2000, the reported average bitrate is **141 kbps**, which is accurate to the opus sound file. The problem comes when attaching a cover to the .mka (same exact source file):

> ffmpeg -i original.opus -acodec copy -attach cover.png -map 0 -metadata:s:t:0 mimetype=image/png -metadata:s:t:0 filename=cover.png output+cover.mka

Now, both MediaInfo and foobar2000 are reporting **456 kbps** for the bitrate, a value that obviously is not correct as the provided Opus doesn't reach that. This issue doesn't seem to happen when i add a cover to an MP3 or OGG file, as the reported bitrate is the exact same with and without cover for those containers. The same exact thing happens when trying to add the cover with Mp3tag or MKVToolNix.

I'm using the latest ffmpeg build for windows. The input opus file is VBR 48kHz.

Is there a way to fix this? Or is this a problem with the Matroska format? Which are my alternatives? Any help is appreciated.